Short story about a bomb that stops time being detonated in London
I read this short story in a science fiction anthology on Kindle within the last four years. It was written in English.
It was about a time bomb (a bomb that stops time) being detonated in London. Everyone outside the affected area thinks everyone within it is dead, but they are not. An agent of some kind has to enter the area and do some science fiction things.

Welcome to the site! When did you read this short story? Was it written in English and read/published in the UK, or was London just a setting and the book could have been from elsewhere? There's a checklist of possible details for story-ID questions, which might help to jog your memory for additional details that could help someone to find the answer faster.

Written in English,read it on kindle,in a science fiction anthology

Quite recently, within the last 4 years

Into Darkness? https://kasmana.people.charleston.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf256

Reminds me a bit of the Take 5 Bomb from Girl Genius, but they've been running that plot line for years now...

Is this "War Crimes" (2020) by Mike Carey...?
It was first published in London Centric: Tales of Future London (2020) and then again in Best of British Science Fiction 2020 (2021).
Centuries in the future, people are linked by the 'voke' and the 'drift,' which enable them to sense one another's thoughts and emotions. As a result, misunderstandings are now a thing of the past, as are hate and war.
However, the effects of old wars still linger, in the form of various sites around the world where people have been frozen in time by time-bombs detonated centuries prior. These time-bombs freeze the people caught within the blast radiuses, but not the space itself, so those who weren't present when the bombs went off can now move freely in those areas. Sadly, those who were present when the bombs went off cannot be unfrozen or affected in any way, and are regarded as dead for all intents and purposes, while the sites are treated as public monuments and memorials.

 Unbeknownst to most, while the majority of people in stasis were frozen in time both physically and mentally — meaning they are effectively braindead — a minority proved partially immune to the time-bombs and weren't frozen mentally. Consequently, those unfortunate individuals have remained fully conscious for centuries, without the ability to move or communicate.

The story focuses on 'London 21' — a portion of Central London where a time-bomb was detonated in the mid-21st century — and Lt. Husnara Begum, a temporal engineer who's called to the site when an individual in stasis there is detected moving.
