A short story about a time slowing bomb that is slowly exploding inside for years
A girl and her brother are at the edge of the bomb zone, 1 or 2 blocks in size.  She is out except her pinky, which they cut off. In the bomb area everyone appears frozen. At the center is an explosion that over decades later the world is watching the people inside slowly turn in horror towards the explosion as time moves so slowly inside. It is the ultimate terrorist attack as they are forced for maybe a hundred years the people inside will be horribly killed.  Every year on the anniversary the sister is interviewed by all the news shows. The short story takes place on the 20th, or some such anniversary of the bomb's start.

Welcome! Do you recall where you read this story and when? Every clue helps! Thank you.

Is this the same story that was asked recently?   Similar theme, a bomb in a city that stops time.  There is a suggested, unconfirmed, answer in the linked thread.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/292464/short-story-about-a-bomb-that-stops-time-being-detonated-in-london?rq=1

@Pete "War Crimes" is definitely not a match.  Except for people being frozen, every other detail is wrong.
